# Missing "clone" option in vSphere

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I'm running VMWare vSphere Client Version 5.5.0.
I'm logged in as an administrative user.

I want to clone a VM (or turn it into a template.)   All the documentation says "Right click on the VM name in Inventory, then select Clone"

Unfortunately when I right click on the VM name I get

```
Power
Guest
Snapshot
Open Console
Edit Settings
Upgrade Virtual Hardware
Add Permission
Report Performance
Rename
Open in New Window
Remove from Inventory
Delete from Disk
```

As you can see "Clone" is not one of the options.  I've looked under all the menus and tabs I can find, with no luck.

What am I missing?

Side note:  I was able to "manually" clone the VM by browsing the data store, creating a new directory, copying the contents of the old directory, and renaming the `vmx` file, then adding the new vmx to inventory, but this is not a very good work-around because among other things, the copied vmdk files were no longer sparse which used up most of the free disk space on the host device!

Comment: From the VMware documentation: **You must be connected to vCenter Server in order to clone a virtual machine. You cannot clone virtual machines if you connect directly to an ESXi host.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're connected to a vCenter, cloning is not an option for the version you're using.